# Strategy Pattern on Heterogeneous Objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I'm learning about the Strategy Pattern and it seems like an amazing alternative to inheritance. I keep thinking about use-cases for it but there's this thing I keep struggling with when I try to connect the dots:

*How does this work when my objects are heterogeneous.*

So, what do I mean by that? The easiest way to explain is with an example I heard. Someone tried to explain this pattern by telling me "Imagine you have a List and the list should be Sortable. You could implement the interface Sortable and add the logic there, but a better alternative is to use composition over inheritance and pass the Sortable behavior to the list when it is constructed, that way you can reuse the sort logic between different types of lists AND you can switch the sorting strategy on the list at runtime"

Cool, so that explanation has the 3 main points I see in the strategy pattern:

1. It favors composition over inheritance, making the code more flexible and maintainable.
2. Because we're not implementing an interface, we are following DRY. If two different lists need the same sorting logic, they won't have to repeat the code in their @Override method. We can reuse because of composition.
3. We could swap the behavior at runtime, which follows the Open/Close principle.

What keeps bugging me is that in order to sort a list we need a lot of information about the list. There are many many types of lists and they all have different internal structures. If the objects are heterogeneus, it would be pretty hard to have a sorting strategy that can be applied to two different types of Lists.

Imagine I have a LinkedList, an ArrayList and a DoublyLinkedList. In order to sort each one of these, I need to dig into the actual state, structures or internals (whatever you want to call them) of each implementation. So, it would be pretty hard to create a strategy that can operate on all of these lists.

- How does the Strategy pattern actually work in these cases?
- Or it isn't meant to be used with heterogeneous objects at all?
- Should strategy be used only if the strategy doesn't need to know any internals of the objects?
- Should it be used only if all the objects can provide the same information to the strategy in order to work?

If the strategy depends on the internals of the objects, it wouldn't be reusable... So, is there any real-life example that can shed light on the actual value of this pattern?

I don't have a final question per se (I asked many questions), but I think my point and concern is clear.

Comment: An example of such heterogenous objects would be handy.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis added some examples of lists

Comment: Thanks for the update. Both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` implement the same interface `List` (I have no idea what is meant with `DoublyLinkedList` as it is exactly the `LinkedList` in the JDK). The sorting behavior uses the methods available through the `List` interface.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Hmm ok, so the list would pass itself to the strategy. Ok, I get your point in general. But specifically to that example, wouldn't it be very inneficient to use those interfaces? And if I'm using the interface why not just creating an utility class that sorts a list using the List interface? And just create a new utility sorting class whenever I need a different sorting behavior. That way my list class wouldn't have to depend on a SortStrategy object.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis `DoublyLinkedList` is **not** an ordinary `LinkedList`.. at least, in Java, as `LinkedList`s are *Singly* `LinkedList`s in Java.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri: According to the docs of [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html): *"Doubly-linked list implementation of the List and Deque interfaces."*

Answer (score 1):

The simplest example of the strategy pattern used is the simple JSK method [`Collections#sort(List, Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) which de-facto uses `Comparator` as the injected behavior that affects the sorting behavior (putting the sorting algorithm itself aside for a while). This method is meant to sort *anything* that is declared as a List regardless of its generic type because this is what the `Comparator` handles with. Hence I would say it is ready to sort any heterogeneous object.

If you feel the approach is not sufficient, feel free to expand the responsibility of the strategy. Here is an example:

```
<T extends List<E>, E> T sortList(T list, SortingStrategy<T, E> strategy) {
    return strategy.sortList(list);
}
```

```
interface SortingStrategy<T extends List<E>, E> {
    T sortList(T list);
}
```

Now the strategies implementations. I use JDK collections but you are not limited to this hierarchy as you can define your own one.

```
class ArrayListSortingStrategy<E> implements SortingStrategy<ArrayList<E>, E> {

    @Override
    public ArrayList<E> sortList(final ArrayList<E> list) {
        return /* ... implementation ... */;
    }
}
```

```
class LinkedListSortingStrategy<E> implements SortingStrategy<LinkedList<E>, E> {

    @Override
    public LinkedList<E> sortList(final LinkedList<E> list) {
        return /* ... implementation ... */;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<String> arrayList = sortList(new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayListSortingStrategy<>());
Deque<String> linkedList = sortList(new LinkedList<>(), new LinkedListSortingStrategy<>());
```

I find the strategy pattern fairly flexible. You can inject further behavior into the constructor of a particular strategy and *nest* the strategies.:

```
public ArrayListSortingStrategy(Comparator<E> comparator) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: I think this is the best it will get, but the issue with this approach is that we know beforehand that we're using an ArrayList, so we need to use an ArrayListSortingStrategy. If we had to figure out the type of the list in runtime, it wouldn't work. Or we would have to break the polymorphism.

Comment: You can define `class ListSortingStrategy<E> implements SortingStrategy<List<E>, E>` which would sort all the implementations of the `List` however, returning the type `List`. I don't know it helps you. I suggest you to **uncheck** my answer as accepted and wait for other answerers as somebody might have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

> ...in order to sort a list we need a lot of information about the list.

Not really. In fact no information about lists is strictly necessary for sorting. Any two [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) elements can be sorted. Whether a specific data structure contains the elements is immaterial. Sorting in Java already works this way.

Basically the entire premise of object-oriented programming is objects that communicate without knowing each other's concrete types. Object-oriented design is an exercise in creating appropriate abstractions to facilitate that communication.

> Should it be used only if all the objects can provide the same information to the strategy in order to work?

Set aside the Strategy pattern for a moment. All of OOP relies on objects providing consistent information to each other. To facilitate this, we create appropriate abstractions that in essence make heterogenous objects appear the same.

Exploring some of Java's sorting implementation should make this more clear. For a start, [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Comparator)) is a good Strategy example, since it composes its `Comparator`. Note the `Comparator` has zero knowledge of the `TreeSet` and indeed, the same `Comparator` could be used in a List.